# Create Textboxes Using Methods or Classes

Tags: c#

I have code for creating textboxes. I'm repeating this code three times in different areas.  I'm trying to learn more about methods and classes, so I would like to know if there is any possibility of creating textboxes using methods or classes without repeating code.

```
        private void incomes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        panel1.Controls.Clear();

        TextBox textbox1 = new TextBox();
        textbox1.Size = new Size(75,23);
        textbox1.Text = "Name";
        textbox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        panel1.Controls.Add(textbox1);

        TextBox textbox2 = new TextBox();
        textbox2.Size = new Size(75, 23);
        textbox2.Text = "Sum";
        textbox2.Location = new Point(80, 0);
        panel1.Controls.Add(textbox2);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely! You can create a method that accepts the differing parameters and creates the textbox with those specifications:

```
private void incomes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Controls.Clear();

    TextBox textbox1 = CreateTextBox("Name", 0);
    TextBox textbox2 = CreateTextBox("Sum",  80);

    // Now you can use the textbox values...
}

private TextBox CreateTextBox(string text, int x)
{
    TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
    textbox.Size = new Size(75, 23);
    textbox.Text = text;
    textBox.Location = new Point(x, 0);
    panel1.Controls.Add(textbox);

    return textbox;
}
```

Comment: Thank tou. But later i need to take value of those textboxes.                                                                                                   `string name = textbox1.Text;
string sum = textbox2.Text;` how can i do that if textboxes names are same?

Comment: You could make the method return the textbox object if you want. I'll update my answer to show you.